# Send a functions parameter to an array in another included file?

Tags: php, arrays, class, email, include

I'm trying to build a user signup class, where I'm using a language file, which I've include to my class. When a user tries to signup, I want my class to send the user an e-mail with information. However, the text I use in my mail function is from the language file. In this language file, I have an array where I call the variable with the username in from the function in the class, but I can't seem to get to work. I searched on the internet, but couldn't find any solution.

If you're wondering what language my language file are in, I can tell it's in Danish.

------ Class file:

```
class User {
  #Variables for mail
  public $mail;
  private $LANG;        
  public function __construct(){
    global $RealName;
    require_once ('_lang/class.langdk.inc.php');
    require_once ('class.phpmailer.php');
    $this->LANG = $LANG;

  }

  public function registerUser($RealName,$UserEmail){
     echo 'Brugeren er oprettet med: ' . $this->LANG['welcome'];
  }
}
```

In my class.langdk.inc.php, I have:

```
$LANG= array(
    #Mailsetup
    'welcome'      => 'Hej '. $RealName .', velkommen som bruger!',
);
```

Comment: Please, change the constructor to `public function __construct($RealName)` and call it as `$User = new User($RealName);`, don't use globals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach :

```
echo 'Brugeren er oprettet med: ' . str_replace('$RealName', $RealName, $this->LANG['welcome']);
```

And :

```
$LANG = array(
    'welcome' => 'Hej $RealName velkommen som bruger!'
);
```

Comment: That was not the goal, obviously.